# I'm getting Overload resolution ambiguity error on kotlin safe call

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I have a nullable string variable `ab`. If I call `toUpperCase` via safe call operator after I assign null to it, kotlin gives error.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var ab:String? = "hello"
    ab = null
    println(ab?.toUpperCase())
}
```

> Error:(6, 16)
>   Overload resolution ambiguity:
>   @InlineOnly public
>   inline fun Char.toUpperCase(): Char defined in kotlin.text
>   @InlineOnly public inline fun String.toUpperCase(): String defined in kotlin.text

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in this [doc about smart-casts](https://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_smart_casts):

> x = y makes x of the type of y after the assignment

The line `ab = null` probably smart casts `ab` to `Nothing?`. If you check `ab is Nothing?` it is indeed `true`.

```
var ab: String? = "hello"
ab = null
println(ab?.toUpperCase())
println(ab is Nothing?) // true
```

Since `Nothing?` is subtype of all types (including `Char?` and `String?`), it explains why you get the `Overload resolution ambiguity` error. The solution for this error will be what Willi Mentzel mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885192/1788806), casting `ab` to the type of `String` before calling `toUpperCase()`.

---

Remarks:
This kind of error will occur when a class implements two interfaces and both interface have extension function of the same signature:

```
//interface
interface A {}
interface B {}

//extension function
fun A.x() = 0
fun B.x() = 0

//implementing class
class C : A, B {}

C().x()    //Overload resolution ambiguity
(C() as A).x()    //OK. Call A.x()
(C() as B).x()    //OK. Call B.x()
```

Comment: Wait, isn't `ab` already defined as a Nullable String in the first line? So why should a cast to String? be necessary?

Comment: @donfuxx Since the type of `ab` is smart casted to `Nothing?` and `Nothing?` is subtype of both `String?` and `Char?`. At the same time, there is a extension function `toUpperCase()` declared with receiver type `String` and `Char`. So, we have to tell the compiler that we want to call the extension function with `String` as the receiver.

Comment: Holy cow, just stepped through the question's code in the debugger and `ab is Nothing?` evaluated to true. So "smart" cast happened I guess.. but probably "dumb" cast would be a better name ;-) I prefer to see this as a kotlin bug like the other answers do, but still thumbs up since this answer helped analyzing :-)

Comment: Nice analysis, that totally makes sense

Comment: just reading this a 2nd time and it makes all sense to me. However I wonder if there exists a case where a smart cast to Nothing? could ever be useful, though

Comment: @donfuxx This is a very constructed case. When do you ever assign `null` to something and then execute a safe-call? The call won't ever be performed anyway. If anything, I would prefer a compiler warning along the lines of "ab is known to be null, call will never be executed".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but that seems to be a bug due to smart casting (to `Nothing?`, subtype of every nullable type). This one works:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var ab: String? = "hello"
    ab = makeNull()
    println(ab?.toUpperCase())
}

fun makeNull(): String? = null
```

The only difference: The compiler does not know the `null` assignment directly, which seems to cause the error in your example. But still, yours should probably work too.

Answer (score 2):

It really seems like a bug. The type `String?` is lost somehow upon assigning `null`, so you have to tell the compiler explicitely that it should deal with a `String?`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var ab: String? = "hello"
    ab = null
    println((ab as String?)?.toUpperCase()) // explicit cast

    // ...or

    println(ab?.let { it.toUpperCase() }) // use let
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to [smart casts](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) used by Kotlin. In other words, Kotlin is able to infer that after this line of code:

```
ab = null
```

type of variable `ab` is simply `null` (this is not actual type you can use in Kotlin - I am simply referring to range of allowed values), not `String?` (in other words, there is **no way** `ab` might contain a `String`).

Considering that toUpperString() extension function is defined only for Char and String (and not Char? or String?), there is no way to choose between them.

To avoid this behaviour see answers proposed by other guys (e.g. explicit casting to String?), but this definitely looks like a feature (and quite a useful one) rather than a bug for me.

Comment: "type of variable ab is simply null" null is not a type!

Comment: "Considering that toUpperString() extension function is defined only for Char and String (and not Char? or String?), there is no way to choose between them." the safe call operator is used, and therefore toUpperString() is never called on ab in case it is null.

Comment: "...there is no way ab might contain a String)" what if I assign ab = "hello2" after the null assignment. suddenly there is *a way* that it contains a String again.

Comment: Yes, there is no `null` type which you can use, but it is likely that compiler might use "kind of" `null` type underneath (basically, imagine Typescript where it is not allowed to use `null` explicitly) when making type inference. This is only assumption, of course, yet the actual behaviour is rather consistent with this assumption. We'll need comment from someone on Kotlin development team to clarify how smart-casts actually work.

Comment: Yes, the compiler *could be* able do decide that no call to `toUpperCase()` would be made anyway, so it could ignore the whole thing completely.  
However, Kotlin devs decided to make this check nevertheless. Whether this is a good decision is the question of personal preference, and for me it seems rather reasonable to make such check.

Comment: I am referring to the particular example of code, not any modifications to it. And still, variable type would remain (kind of) `null` up to the point where new assignment is made.

Comment: ...oh, my bad, I didn't see the smart cast note on this answer :/

Answer (score 1):

I decompiled your function and I figured: after the moment you make `ab = null` the compiler will smartcast it, putting `null` `(ACONST_NULL)` in every ocurrence of `ab`. Then as `null` has no type. you can't infer the type for the receiver of `toUpperCase()`.

This is the java equivalent code generated from the kotlin byte code:

```
public final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
   Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
   String ab = "hello";
   ab = (String)null;
   Object var3 = null;
   System.out.println(var3);
}
```

It looks as an issue that should be resolved by the kotlin team.

Comment: Note: I used `toInt` instead of `toUpperCase` to be able to compile/decompile the code