# "Overload resolution ambiguity error" resolved with another overload

Tags: kotlin

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884934/im-getting-overload-resolution-ambiguity-error-on-kotlin-safe-call).

How can it be that with this line added

```
fun Int.toUpperCase() = ""
```

This problem

> Error:(6, 16)
>   Overload resolution ambiguity:
>   @InlineOnly public
>   inline fun Char.toUpperCase(): Char defined in kotlin.text
>   @InlineOnly public inline fun String.toUpperCase(): String defined in kotlin.text

goes away for this piece of code?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var ab: String? = "hello"
    ab = null
    println(ab?.toUpperCase())
}
```

The answer given for the reference question makes sense, it just doesn't answer what is happening here.

Comment: Indeed, that's some head-scratching material :)

Answer (score 0):

It even works if you define `fun String.toUpperCase() = ""` in your file again. The compiler chooses the *locally defined function* to be used and won't consider the ambiguous ones anymore. Since `ab` becomes `Nothing?` and this is the subtype of all nullable types, any receiver will make this happen.

Shown here:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("hello".substringBefore("e"))
}

fun String.substringBefore(e: String) = "hey"
```

`substringBefore` from stdlib will not be invoked because the locally defined extension is used.