# Overload Resolution Ambiguity Error on null-able string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, overload-resolution

Throwing a **Overload Resolution Ambiguity error** on println(Toby) statement.
If I don't reassign value of var Toby to null the code works. If I reassign var Toby any non null value it works. What is going wrong?

```
var Toby:String? = "Pizza time"

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  Toby = null //if I comment it out then the error goes away ... WHY?

  if(Toby != null){
    println(Toby) // error here
  } else {
    println("I'm gonna put some dirt in your eye")
  }

}
```

Comment: (Confirmed with the latest plug-in; IDE syntax checker, IDE compiler, and command-line compiler all complain.  The error makes no sense to me; only the expected `Any?` overload takes a nullable parameter, so I can't see why any of the other overloads are considered.  And since the parameter is a mutable variable which could change between the assignment and call, I can't see how the assignment could make any difference.  Interestingly, a workaround is to add `as String?`.  Could this be a compiler bug?)

Comment: I was confused by this behavior too, and it still seems to be present in 2023.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting Overload resolution ambiguity error on kotlin safe call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884934/im-getting-overload-resolution-ambiguity-error-on-kotlin-safe-call)